# How to stream data from Twilio to openai Whisper

Tags: python, twilio, audio-streaming, twilio-api, openai-whisper

with the below code, the result ends up just being always the same "Thank you." Any ideas what could be going wrong. For reference, I used the [load_audio](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/audio.py#L26) function in the whisper package. And an article about [twilio and Vosk](https://www.twilio.com/blog/transcribe-phone-calls-text-real-time-twilio-vosk).

```py
@sock.route('/stream')
def stream(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        packet = json.loads(message)
    if packet['event'] == 'media':
            # get audio as ulaw
            audio = base64.b64decode(packet['media']['payload'])
            add_audio(audio)

buffer = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)

def add_audio(audio):
    global buffer
    # convert audio to numpy array
    audio = np.frombuffer(audio, np.int16).flatten().astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
    buffer = np.concatenate((buffer, audio))
    process_audio()


def process_audio():
    global buffer
    audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(buffer)
    mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)
    mel = torch.nan_to_num(mel)
    result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)
```

Answer (score -4):

Che mi kontentige funkcias [tiu programo](https://gist.github.com/AndreasKueck/84c4dddcd43f631959bc3aeadf6a09ba):

```
# Per Whisper de OpenAI jen realtempa transskribo de telefonvoko al Twilio-numero.
# Temas pri adapto de tio, kion priskribas jena artikolo:
# "Realtempa vocho-al-teksto-transformo de telefonvoko en Esperanto per Twilio kaj VOSK";
# ligilo: https://medium.com/westphoenizier/realtempa-vocho-al-teksto-transformo-de-telefonvoko-en-esperanto-per-twilio-kaj-vosk-5d6cf5ef78c1 

import audioop
import base64
import json
import openai
import wave
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sock import Sock
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Start
from twilio.rest import Client

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)
twilio_client = Client()

openai.api_key = "openaishlosilo" # Anstatauigu per la vera OpenAI-shlosilo komencighanta per sk-
audio_data2 = b'' 
transcription0 = ''
i = 0

@app.route('/call', methods=['POST'])
def call():
    """Accept a phone call."""
    response = VoiceResponse()
    start = Start()
    start.stream(url=f'wss://{request.host}/stream')
    response.append(start)
    response.say('Bonwole parolu nun.', voice='Polly.Ewa')
    response.pause(length=60)
    print('Eniranta voko de numero kashita por privateco')
    return str(response), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

@sock.route('/stream')
def handle_audio(ws):
    global audio_data2
    global transcription0
    global i
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            print('Neniu mesagho ricevita')
            continue
        data = json.loads(message)
        if data['event'] == "start":
            print('Elsendfluo startis')
        elif data['event'] == "stop":
            print('\nElsendfluo haltis')
        elif data['event'] == "media":
            i = i + 1
            payload = data['media']['payload']
            audio_data = base64.b64decode(payload)
            audio_data = audioop.ulaw2lin(audio_data, 2)
            audio_data = audioop.ratecv(audio_data, 2, 1, 8000, 16000, None)[0]
            audio_data2 = audio_data2 + audio_data
            if len(audio_data2) > 299999:
                sondosiero = 'sono' + str(i) + '.wav'
                with wave.open(sondosiero, 'w') as wavfile:
                    wavfile.setnchannels(1)
                    wavfile.setsampwidth(2)
                    wavfile.setframerate(16000)
                    wavfile.writeframes(audio_data2)
                    wavfile.close()
                audio_file3 = open(sondosiero, "rb")
                try:
                    transcription = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file3)
                    if (transcription != transcription0):
                        print(transcription.text + ' ')
                        transcription0 = transcription
                    audio_file3.close()
                except:
                    pass
                os.remove(sondosiero)
                audio_data2 = b''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pyngrok import ngrok
    ngrok.set_auth_token("ngrokshlosilo") # Anstatauigu per la vera ngrok-shlosilo
    port = 5008
    public_url = ngrok.connect(port, bind_tls=True).public_url
    number = twilio_client.incoming_phone_numbers.list()[0]
    number.update(voice_url=public_url + '/call')
    public_urlc = public_url + '/call'
    print(f'Atendante vokojn al {number.phone_number}')
    app.run(port=port)
```

Comment: Please translate this into English